# Position Element to Center of Selected Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please visit this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pitcairn/fgdcd9Lv/1/) before you proceed.

Select the text on the document, on the **second attempt** you should be able to spawn a button with text *test*.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to spawn the element at the *top center* of the selected range on the document. For example refer the screenshot below:

[image: Desired solution.]

The current JS code:

```
var position = '';
function getSelectedTextPos(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rect;
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        var selection = document.getSelection();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rect;
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        var selection = document.selection.createRange();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rect;
    }
}
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    position = getSelectedTextPos();
    console.log(position);
});

$("button").click(function (e) {
    console.log("Hello");
});

var selectedText = '';
function getSelectedText(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}

function checkSelectionChanged() {
    var current = getSelectedText();
    console.log(current);
    if(current != selectedText) {
        selectedText = current;
        if(selectedText != '') {
            $('#quote').offset(position);
            $('#quote').show();
        } else {
            $('#quote').hide();
        }
    }
}

setInterval(checkSelectionChanged, 250);
```

I have tried various permutations and combinations to achieve it, but to no avail.

How it works on Chrome:

[image: Working on Chrome]

How it works on FireFox:

[image: Working on FireFox]

Comment: I selected the text many times but no button with text - 'test' was popped up. I saw a button with text 'Test' at the very bottom of your document. I was not popped when I selected the text. Do you want to achieve this? Do you want to know how you can make the button _popup_??

Comment: @RohitKumar, I would want the button to popup right in the center of selected text.

Comment: you said in your desc. that the button will popup if I select the text in the document but It is not happening so..

Comment: @RohitKumar - It does work for me on chrome.

Comment: @RohitKumar - Check the screenshots in my question. I have added both mozilla and chrome.